# Kivy: Long Image not showing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, kivy

I have a very basic program for testing purposes.
Here is the Python code:

```
class TestImage(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestImage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Here is the kv code.

```
<TestImage>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        id: bg_img
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
        size_hint_y: None
        height: Window.height
        source: 'template.jpg'
```

Here is the image in question:
[image: template.jpg]

This is just the base image, and the goal is to scroll through this long image. But for testing purposes I used a simple boxlayout. Other images work fine. But this particular image does not. This image was generated using numpy and opencv using the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
test_img = np.full((11400, 2550, 3), 255, np.uint8)
cv.imwrite('template.jpg', test_img)
```

Kivy only shows a black screen. How can I manage to display this image?
Things I've tried:

1. Converted the image to other formats (png/tiff) still does not work
2. Manipulating the size inside the kv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I exceeded the maximum size that is able to be rendered as pointed out in the console log:

```
[INFO] [GL ] Texture max size 8192.
```

In my case it was 8192. Anymore than that and kivy shows a black screen.
The solution was to chop/resize the image down in such a way that it would result into a reasonable size within the limit